# Play framework logging into several files

Tags: java, logging, playframework, logback

I'm using play framework logger (play.logger) and I need to log different log levels into separate files. I'm new with play and this is first time I have to use logger.

I need to know what to enter in this file to make logging into more files. .
Here's my conf/logger.xml file:

```
<configuration>
 <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" level="INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
 <file>${application.home}/logs/info.log</file>
 <encoder>
   <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
 </encoder>
 </appender>


 <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
 <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

 <root level="ERROR">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
 </root>

</configuration>
```

Thank you in advance on your answers

Comment: Play uses Logback for its logging. You may wish to add the *logback* tag to your question.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/q/30624291