# Is it possible to send log messages to different files with Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using PlayFramework 2.2.2 and I'm very interested in knowing if is possible to log my app in different files and how to do it.

I would like to have different files for different controllers not for different levels.

I have test it to mix several filenames inside conf/application-logger.conf as [official documentation of Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger) says, but I can't find any way to do it.

Comment: Seems like it is SLF4J with logback (the native logger implementation of SLF4J), so the official documentation is actually http://www.slf4j.org/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your play framework version you must customize your logback from [play doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger):

> If you want to fully customize logback, just define a
>   conf/application-logger.xml or conf/logger.xml configuration file.
>   Here is the default configuration file used by Play:

In play framework 4 is logback.xml. For you I think that the easy way is creating custom loggers like this:

1st create a custom logger in your controller:

```
private static final Logger.ALogger CustomLogger = Logger.of("custom");
```

like this:

```
package controllers;


import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.*;



public class Application extends Controller {

    private static final Logger.ALogger CustomLogger = Logger.of("custom");

    public Result index() {



        String toNormal = "this goes normal way";
        String tolevelInfo = "this goes to info";
        String toCustom = "this goes to custom";

        Logger.info(tolevelInfo);



        Logger.error(toNormal);
        Logger.debug(toNormal);
        Logger.warn(toNormal);

        CustomLogger.info(toCustom);



        return ok("Take a look of your logs files");
    }

}
```

2) second you should write a configuration file like this, this also has an example for filtering by level, and creates 3 files application.log, customfile.log and filtrolevelinfo.log:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel - %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

    <appender name="FILTROLEVELINFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <file>${application.home}/logs/filtrolevelinfo.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CUSTOM" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/customfile.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>




    <!--
      The logger name is typically the Java/Scala package name.
      This configures the log level to log at for a package and its children packages.
    -->
  <logger name="play" level="DEBUG"/>

  <logger name="application" level="DEBUG"/>

    <logger name="custom" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM" />
    </logger>


  <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILTROLEVELINFO" />
  </root>



</configuration>
```

with this you should get this three files and the outputs for 1 call tho the method:

application.log:

```
2015-06-03 20:02:20,838 [INFO] from play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider in pool-15-thread-2 - Starting application default Akka system: application
2015-06-03 20:02:20,903 [INFO] from play.core.server.NettyServer$ in pool-15-thread-2 - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

customfile.log:

```
2015-06-03 20:02:30,997 [INFO] from custom in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 - this goes to custom
```

filtrolevelinfo.log:

```
2015-06-03 20:02:30,748 [INFO] from play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider in ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1 - Starting application default Akka system: application
2015-06-03 20:02:30,889 [INFO] from play.api.Play$ in ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1 - Application started (Dev)
2015-06-03 20:02:30,995 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 - this goes to info
2015-06-03 20:02:30,997 [INFO] from custom in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 - this goes to custom
```

I hope this helps you ;-)